# Can ReferenceArrayInput in react-admin support drag and drop ordering?

Tags: drag-and-drop, react-admin

I would like to be able to easily order the tags that in my ReferenceArrayInput within react-admin by dragging and dropping the tags into the correct location.  I am using  within the ReferenceArrayInput.

```
<SimpleForm>
  <ReferenceArrayInput style={{width: "95%"}} label="Workouts" reference="workouts" source="workoutIds" allowEmpty>
    <AutocompleteArrayInput />
  </ReferenceArrayInput>
</SimpleForm>
```

Currently the order is simply set by the order that the workouts tags are added, but I would like to be able to drag and drop the tags and put them in the correct order.

[image: example of ReferenceArrayInput with some items]

Comment: The only way to do that is to write your own component, based (or not) on `ReferenceArrayInput`. At least, react admin core team will not write one.